# Scheme doing more than one job in one if condition

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to do more than one task in one if condition, here is my code:

```
(define (dont-tolerate-fools hist0 hist1 hist2 count)
  (cond ((> 10 count)  'c)
    ((< 10 count)  (soft-tit-for-tat hist0 hist1 hist2))
    ((> 10 count)  (dont-tolerate-fools hist0 hist1 hist2 (+ 1 count)))))
```

It didn't work, because I saw that one of the conditions is true it returns it and break. I am trying to make it return 'c for the first 10 time after that it should behave according to something else.

There may be different ways to do it, but I am interesting in how can I do 2 jobs by checking only one if condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the "count" will be bigger than 10, later it wont call dont-tolerate-fools again

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something for the first 10 times you are called, then something else afterwards, the easiest way is to have some kind of "local" variable to count how many times you've been called, such as:

```
(define func
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda ()
      (cond
        ((< count 10) 
         (set! count (+ count 1))
         'a)
        (else 'b)))))


(for/list ((i (in-range 15)))
  (func))
=> '(a a a a a a a a a a b b b b b)
```

You can also see in that example that you can have multiple forms or values after the condition:

```
  (cond
    ((< count 10) 
     (set! count (+ count 1))   ; action 1
     'a)                        ; action 2
```

OTOH, if this was simply supposed to be a loop then you're missing a stop condition and one call:

```
(define (func (n 0))
  (cond 
    ((> n 15)
     'stop)
    ((< n 10)
     (display 'c)
     (func (+ n 1)))
    (else
      (display 'x)
      (func (+ n 1)))))

(func)
=> ccccccccccxxxxxx'stop
```

Comment: It is not the only thing I care printing the correct result. I wonder that whether it is possible to call 2 functions in just one if clause..  -or something equal to this

Comment: For *cond* we have shown you can. For *if* you also can, but you need to group them with a *begin* form.

Comment: Yes "begin" is what I want. Thanks

Comment: *cond* doesn't need a *begin* form for multiple actions, so that's why nobody answered this in the first place. *if* does need the *begin* form in that case. If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: OK I see that. I didn't know I can do multiple actions using "cond". You answered my question in your comment and I vote it. If you still want to me accept your answer I can, it is no problem, but this is more fair I think

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but feel free to leave the question unaccepted if you think that it has not been answered entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `cond` is:

```
(cond (<predicate> <body> ...)
      ...)
```

where `<body> ...` means that **any number of expressions**.  So you can simply rewrite your code as:

```
(define (dont-tolerate-fools hist0 hist1 hist2 count)
  (cond ((> 10 count)  
         (dont-tolerate-fools hist0 hist1 hist2 (+ 1 count)) 
         'c) 
        ((< 10 count)  (soft-tit-for-tat hist0 hist1 hist2))))
```